# Azure SQL - bulk insert from Azure files and not blobs

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I have a ruby app in azure container for which I have mounted an azure storage. The app uploads few files to mounted drive which needs to be picked up by azure sql for bulk insert and processing. Now, from this article https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/BringYourOwnStorage/mounting_azure_blob.md mounting the blob storage is readonly, I can use azure files for mounting but azure sql doesn't give any option to directly bulk insert from azure files. so I have got stuck between azure files vs blobs, please help me out...

Comment: Hi, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL Database only supports reading from Azure Blob Storage.

File Storage is not supported.

Ref: [BULK INSERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

I would suggest you choose Blob Storage.

HTH.